# copy filtered content of file to remote server via rsync

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I know how to copy files between servers using rsync.
But I was looking for an option where I donot want to copy entire content file on another server.
Example:- I want to copy **/var/log/messages** filtered by **todays date** on remote server in **todays date folder** and **tomorrows content** in **tomorrows date folder** and so on. Though I can achieve the same by creating temporary files in local node before transferring, but I am looking for a solution where **filtered data can be transferred** to remote server **without creating any local temporary file**

Answer (score 1):

> where filtered data can be transferred to remote server without creating any local temporary file

Just the same way you do locally, just cat the output to the remote. Along:

```
cat /var/log/messages | awk 'some filtering here' | ssh server 'cat > /the/destination'
```

Repeat the process for each file.

The simpler is just the same as creating temporary files you want to transfer - just create them at the destination! Mount `sshfs` the remote and create them inside the mountpoint.

---

> I am looking forward for a solution which works with rsync

It's easy to say: create a FUSE filesystem that applies mentioned filtering on top of existing "bottom" paths transparently. So that reading from a file will result in reading the filtered data only. This sounds like a rather extensive project involving a lot of time. Then use rsync of top of such FUSE filesystem. The filtering will then be done transparently by the code implementing the filesystem.

Another idea: overall, as of now, rsync does not support any kind of "content filtering/parsing" to the transferred files. rsync is overall a network communication protocol. Take rsync sources and implement such functionality inside the rsync server - before transferring each file, apply a function that transforms the file content, i.e. does the filtering that you want.

Comment: While the solution you mentioned will work, but I am looking forward for a solution which works with rsync. Usage of rsync is to ensure that data is transferred only when required.

Comment: Either rsync, or filtering, you con't do both (?). If you want to rsync, you _have to_ have files. It's not a tool for that.

Comment: @AppLogin : Since you want to transfer only part of a file, this requirement does not make sense in the context of _rsync_. You would have to develop your own solution.